# Combine Google Sheets Query, IMPORTRANGE, and AVERAGE functions

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to aggregate an average value using Query and IMPORTRANGE so I can compare the index numbers of the two tables.

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Table ","Sheet!B:C"),"Select avg(Col2) where Col1='"&A2&"'",0)`

File 1:

| Table 1 Index | Above formula |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet!I:J"),"Select avg(Col2) where Col1='"&A2&"'",0) |

File 2:

| Table 2 Index | Table 1 Index Match | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2.0 |
| 2 | 1 | 10.0 |

But it returns empty. When I remove `avg()`, then I get an error that the dataset is empty. So somewhere I made a mistake, and it's not comparing File 2 Column B against File 1 Column A properly. I have the `IMPORTRANGE()` selecting columns B and C, so that means I'm trying to average `Col2` and comparing `Col1` to `A2`, but I can't see the error there.

Comment: I don't know what happened to the formatting, the table looks all janked... I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Can you provide at least a screenshot of your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet!B:C"), 
 "select Col1,avg(Col2) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1
  label avg(Col2)''", 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround and incorporated a hidden "Meta Data" tab.

I used `IMPORTRANGE()` to get all of the Table 1 indices that could exist into Sheet 2 Meta Data tab, did an `AVERAGEIF()` down column 2 that would aggregate Table 2's data into an average if it matches the imported range in column 1. Then just used a `VLOOKUP(IMPORTRANGE())` combo in Sheet 1 Table 1 to bring the aggregation back.